# How to set the OrbitControls target to move around?

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js

I want the orbitcontrols to use a selected object as the new target to "move around". I found a center/target attribute, but I'm not sure how to set it to an object I selected.

I tried this:

```
var controls = this.controls = new THREE.EditorControls(camera, container.dom);

this.orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
this.orbitControls.damping = 0.5;
this.orbitControls.addEventListener( 'change', SceneManager.animate );

 var controls = this.controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, container.dom);
 onObjectselected(function(o){
    controls.center.fromArray([o.position.x, o.position.y, o.position.z]);
 });

controls.addEventListener('change', function () {
    thisView.transformControls.update();
    thisView.orbitControls.update();
    SignalHub.signals.cameraChanged.dispatch(camera);
});
```

but I don't get any results. I used the threejs editor as a code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well nevermind, i don't want to delete this, so I'll let it up.

I somehow thought the controls would manage the other stuff, but I just had to add the following to the objectSelected callback:

```
onObjectselected(function(o){
  //controls.center.fromArray([o.position.x, o.position.y, o.position.z]);
  thisView.orbitControls.center.fromArray([o.position.x, o.position.y, o.position.z]);
});
```